# ERROR: Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, async-await, .net-framework-version

I have following configuration of my PC:

- Windows 8
- Visual Studio 2012
- .NET Framework 4.5

My Project Configuration is:

- WP 7.1
- Silverlight 4.0
- .NET Framework 4.0
- CTP ASYNC (installed, using async and await keywords)

The project was written using VS2010 on Windows 7 machine for WP7.1. Now I have upgraded the PC to Windows 8 and have installed VS2012.

The project, however, complaining about  'async' modifier.

Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?

Any idea how to solve this problem?

thank you!

Comment: I tried to download Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 2012 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576), but the packager manager complains that I have silverlight version 4 and WindowsPhone71.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a newer version of the Async targeting package which supports Silverlight 4. Search for [Microsoft.BCL.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) in NuGet, or run `install-package Microsoft.Bcl.Async –pre`in the Package Manager Console. The package supports SL4, WP 7.1+ and Portable Libraries (yes!)

You will find a detailed description in the BCL team's blog [Using async/await without .NET Framework 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/19/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From the page you downloaded from:

> This targeting pack is not required for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET for Windows Store apps. It is only required for projects targeting Silverlight 5 and .NET Framework 4.0. Earlier platform releases are not supported.

Upgarde to Silverlight 5?

Comment: There are two problems... (1) How can I upgrade to silverlight 5? I have WP8 SDK installed and I believe I have SL5 as well. but how can I upgrade? (2) I can upgrade to Silverlight 4, but using some external tools written in silverlight 4, not sure if all of them will work.