# Cannot find all the types required by the async modifier

Tags: .net, silverlight, asynchronous, dynamics-crm-2011

I've checked the several questions I found online on this matter and still I get this error.
I'm using Silverlight 5.0 and .Net Framework version 4.5 with crm 2011 and this is my function below:

```
async private void getDatafromCRM()
{     
    // ..... code to prepare the query expression
    IOrganizationService service = SilverlightUtility.GetSoapService();
    var response = await service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
}
```

The error I get :

> (extension)
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskIOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase
>   query)
>
> Error:    Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are
>   you targetting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to
>   an assembly ?

I installed the "Async Target package and i got the message that it was added to my solution, why am i still getting this error ?

I'm using async in my silverlight project not in the web application project. I noticed that the package was added to the Web project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ERROR: Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974610/error-cannot-find-all-types-required-by-the-async-modifier-are-you-targeting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` to your Silverlight project. Do *not* add it to your web project.